# inset box shadow not working in my case?

Tags: css

```
div{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:pink;
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #000;
}
```

Above css worked but when I do  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 3px #000; is wasn't work, I also tried  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #000 inset. Any idea?

Comment: It is working for me http://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/tfw0rrtv/

Comment: can you add *jsfiddle* of it? and what browser you are using?

Comment: try `box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #000 inset` i.e. remove `;` *semicolun* which is after it.. It will work :)

Answer (score 0):

try it with smaller number of parameters:

```
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px #000;
```

or with specified engine:

```
-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0px 0px 10px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px #000000;
 box-shadow:        inset 0px 0px 10px #000000;
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of box-shadow property is as follows:

```
box-shadow: none|h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color |inset|initial|inherit;
```

You are not setting any value to h-shadow and v-shadow. That is why you are not able to see a shadow.
Try this code

```css
div {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```